# Why my event listener not behaving correctly, as my function do,, sharing the same functionality?

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener

Why is my event listener not behaving correctly, as my function do, sharing the same functionality?

I need to hide the row in a table, based on the input in the search bar.
The below is the functionality I have tried.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

I want this to be implemented in Event listener, instead of function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Filter Table</title>
        
        <style>
            body{
                font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
                font-family: 'M PLUS 2', sans-serif;
            }
            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            input[type = "text"]{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 96%;
                margin: 0 50px;
                padding: 10px 35px 10px 35px;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
                font-family: 'M PLUS 2', sans-serif;
                background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-512.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 30px;
                background-position: 3px 6px; 
            }
            #myTable{
                width: 96%;
                border: 1px solid rgb(197, 194, 194);
                margin: 10px 50px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            #myTable td,th{
                text-align: left;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            tr{
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }
            #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover{
                background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2><b>My Customers</b></h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." onkeyup="myFunction()"  id="myInput" >
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th style="width: 60%;"><b>Name</b></th>
                <th style="width: 40%;"><b>Country</b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
                <td>Sweden</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>North/South</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paris specialites</td>
                <td>France</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        // Function to filter the table, based on search
        function myFunction() {
            
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                }
                else{
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                }       
            }
        }
        
        // Event Listener, to filter the table, based on search
        // var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
        // input.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //     var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
        //     var row = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        //     var value = input.value;
        //     var ex_val = value.toUpperCase();
        //     for(var i=1;i < row.length;i++){
        //         var content = row[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]; 
        //         var ex_con = content.textContent.toUpperCase();
        //         if ( ex_con.indexOf(ex_val) > -1){
        //             row[i].style.display = '';
        //         }
        //         else{
        //             row[i].style.display = 'none';
        //         }
        //     }
        // })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `keyup` and `click` are not the same. Even then: both versions appear to work. I wouldn’t use either. Use the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead.

Comment: I want the rows to hide when the user search doesn't match the table value. and only rows to be displayed, that are matching the user's search. But when I try to implement it using an event listener, it doesn't work, as it does for function. It also shows no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the error.
I was giving click / onkeypress in event listener, instead of "input".
Now, the rows are hiding and displaying correctly for the event listeners.

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        input.addEventListener('input',function(){
            var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
            var row = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
            for(var i=1;i<row.length;i++){
                var td = row[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                var value = td.textContent;
                if(value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
                    
                    row[i].style.display = '';
                }
                else{
                    row[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        })
```